# Why if three numbers a, b and c satisfy the triangle inequality, they can make up a triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We are asked to prove that given three positive numbers a, b and c, such that

$$
a < b + c\\
b < a + c\\
c < a + b,
$$

then there exists a triangle whose sides have lengths $a,b$ and $c$.

They call this the Side-Side-Side Triangle Construction, and we just proved the Pythagorean Theorem, so we're advised to use it here.

No circumferences can be made at this point in the textbook.

Edit: I had written the inequalities wrong as someone pointed out. I meant that each one of the sides is less than the sum of the other two.
Also, a, b and c, are positive real numbers.

Comment: Don't your inequalities imply (assuming you meant to write $\geq$ instead of $>$, and also that $a,b,c\geq0$) that all three numbers are zero? For instance, $a\geq b+c\geq 2b+a$ implies $b=0$.

Comment: Are you reading Euclid's "Elements?" If not, then you should.

Comment: I think you mean $\leq$ and not >, right?

Comment: @SAWblade You're basically correct, but non-degenerate triangles require strict inequality, i.e., $\lt$ rather than $\le$.

Comment: It is very embarrassing that I wrote the inequalities so badly.  Now it is fixed. Basically, we have to prove that whenever three positive quantities satisfy the Triangle Inequality, you can make up a triangle which sides have those measures.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Converse

Comment: I didn't notice that the statement is actually the converse. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Advising to read "Euclid's "Elements" in the original text ? Maybe for a precise statement, in order to see the way Euclid was reasoning, but IMHO a young person (as I can judge by the photo) has better to do than reading "Elements" that have now only an historical interest.

Comment: @JeanMarie: In Book 1 Euclid gives a geometric proof of the converse to the triangle inequality, no need for the Pythagorean Theorem. From the pedagogical viewpoint, Euclid's "Elements" (at least Book 1) or a book following a similar route, such as Kiselev, still provides the best synthetic introduction to elementary geometry. For comparison, I would not recommend Greenberg's book as the main source, only as a supplement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider side *a*, draw a line equal to it's length and call the 2 endpoints *B* and *C*; then using your compass, draw a circle with origin C and radius *b* (call it *C1*) and another circle with origin *B* and radius *c* (call it *C2*); now I claim that there are 2 intersections between *C1* and *C2*,because the sum of the 2 radius's (*a* and *b*) is greater than *a* (if we had *b + c < a*, then there wouldn't be any intersections). Call these 2 points of intersection *P* and *Q*, then any of the triangles *PBC* or *QBC* represent a triangle with sides *a*, *b*, *c* (due to the way we constructed them)